# Sharepoint Content Editor Webpart changing content

Tags: sharepoint, editor

In my document library I have a number of HTML files with the calender month on them (e.g. July 2011.htm, August 2011.htm through to December 2012). I have a Content Editor webpart that displays the HTML file for the current month. At the moment I am manually changing the Content Link of the webpart every month to display the new content - is there some way of doing this automatically using script. I do not have Sharepoint Designer, and am on Sharepoint 2007

Answer (score 0):

Use getMonth() method of javascript to get the current month.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

Once you have the  month, you can append it with the location of  your html file and output the link. Note that you can also put the javascript in CEWP web part:

http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.com/2007/07/adding-javascript-to-content-editor-web.html

Comment: Thanks Madhur, This is my first crack at Sharepoint, I'm not really familiar with javascript, my background is VB. From your links I can see 1. I should rename my file to something like "mm yyyy" and then I can use getmonth and getfullyear. What I am still not clear about is how to output the link to display into my webpart in the same way as the content link does.

Comment: You do not need to rename files and you should not do. You can have a javascript function which returns the same name as file. You might need to bit of parsing and programming. To output, you can use document.write method of javascript http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0420__HTML-Tags/Anchor.htm